# ion-range with dual knobs displaying currency format numbers

Tags: angular, html, css, typescript, ionic3

I'm developing a form in which i use a dual knobs input type range to indicate a price interval .

I need a solution that allows me to show the price variation on the knobs with a currency format, ex: 5.000,00$. 
I have tried with pin="true" but I don't know how to format the text through this attribute.

If you have it is appreciated also an angular solution

Thank you

Comment: Without example code, and how to reproduce it is hard to help your problem specifically and only general answers can be provided. It would help to answer if you provided an example. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)